# Office.Interop.Word - app.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone; Not Disabling Alerts

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

I'm trying to disable read-only alerts when opening word files in C#. I initially tried `app.DisplayAlerts = false`. This did not work and I believe it's because I have a newer version of word. Now, using `word.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone` does not disable the popups either. I'm not sure why, as I've seen several StackOverflow posts indicating that it should. Here's my code (part of a method to convert doc to docx):

```
Application app = new Application();

app.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;

var sourceFile = new FileInfo(path);

var document = app.Documents.Open(sourceFile.FullName);

string newFileName = sourceFile.FullName.Replace(".doc", ".docx");
document.SaveAs2(newFileName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument,
    CompatibilityMode: WdCompatibilityMode.wdWord2010);
app.ActiveDocument.Close();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
app.Quit();
app = null;
GC.Collect();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered opening the document readonly thereby preventing the readonly message altogether?

Comment: @Boeryepes this was the solution. Thank you. I ended up creating a an object called readOnly which was set to true and passing that as the third argument in the Documents.Open call.

Comment: Cool! I will add this s as the answer. Please Mark it as the best answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered opening the document readonly? That prevents the readonly alert. You have to pass the readonly:=true to the document.open method.